# Error while trying to implement custom functions

Tags: lua

This is my very first post. So what i am trying to reach is implementing my custom functions inside the lua math library

What i have tried is turning math to a meta-table and setting __index[] on it, what i was expecting was the function to be implemented there, but lua throws an error at me which i don't know how to solve

Here is the error i get:

```
lua: mathx.lua:14: attempt to index a nil value (field '__index')
```

Here is my code:

```
debug.setmetatable(math, {})

function Round(num, places)
    local decimals = 10^places or 0
    num = num*decimals

    if num >= 0 then
        return math.floor(num + 0.5)/decimals
    end
end

mt = getmetatable(math)
mt.__index["Round"] = Round

I appreciate any answers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `mt.__index` doesn't exist (it's nil), you can either initialize it at the beginning:

```
debug.setmetatable(math, { __index = {} })
```

Or assign a table to it later:

```
mt.__index = {}
mt.__index["Round"] = Round
```

Or use a single statement:

```
mt.__index = { Round = Round }
```

Answer (score 4):

A few more notes:

- There is no need to use `debug.setmetatable`. Since `math` is a regular table, `setmetatable` will work just fine.
- In fact there is no need to use a metatable at all - `math` is not "write-protected" in any way. Using a metatable will just make the code more difficult to understand - conceptually, you're making `math` inherit your methods.
- Using a metatable will likely be slower than modifying the `math` table, since it requires two table indexing operations - one into the `math` table (which fails) and one into the metatable (which succeeds).

If you want to *force* your method, potentially overwriting a previous method, simply use `math.Round = function(num, places) ... end`. You can also use the syntactic sugar of `function math.Round(num, places) ... end` here.

If you want to *keep* a potential previous implementation, use `math.Round = math.Round or function(num, places) ... end`.

Answer (score 1):

With `debug.setmetatable()` you can do this...

```
debug.setmetatable((1), {__index = math}) -- ??? How @#*!~ simple is THIS?
-- Every Number has all math library functions now attached as methods
-- Like every String has string functions attached as methods
-- Test it...
print(("%s\nDegress: %.f\nRadiants: %.48f\nDice: %d"):format(("brandnew methods for datatype number"):upper(), (1).pi:deg(), (180):rad(), (1):random(6)))
```

From now you can simply add math Functions (like `Round(num, places)`) to `math` Library and all Numbers have it immediately as Methods.
Like you can add Functions to `string` Library to use them for every String as Methods.

This is what i mean with 'Like every String has string functions attached as methods'

```
for key, value in pairs(getmetatable("Some String").__index) do
 print(("%s => %s"):format(key, type(value)))
end
```

Output Example

```
> for key, value in pairs(getmetatable("Some String").__index) do print(("%s => %s"):format(key, type(value))) end
sub => function
rep => function
upper => function
len => function
gfind => function
rot => function -- Simply added to string library by me
-- My rot.lua (de/obfuscating function for strings)
-- Added with: string.rot = require("rot")
find => function
match => function
char => function
dump => function
gmatch => function
reverse => function
byte => function
format => function
gsub => function
lower => function
```

The last Reference
If `string` and `package.loaded.string` are `nil` (not existing) because of thinking: Sandboxing
The last Reference will be the `__index` Metamethod of the Metatable of Datatype `string`

```
-- Destroy
string, package.loaded.string = nil, nil
-- Check
print(("Hello World!"):upper(), string, package.loaded.string)
-- Restore
package.loaded.string = getmetatable("Hello World!")['__index']
string = require("string")
-- Check
print(("Hello World!"):upper(), string, package.loaded.string)
```

Therefore the Metatable has to be destroyed to